# After asking question in Siri launch an app and display asked question results

Tags: ios, xcode11, siri, sirikit

I want to integrate `Sirikit` with the app. Sample Instructions I want to give is in the following format:

```
"Search <Something> in <App>"
```

When the user asks the above text to `Siri`, `Siri` will pass this text to my app and open respective screen and display the search results using this asked text.

I have gone through the many SiriKit tutorials but I am confused with the `SiriKit's supported Domains` or `Intent` to choose. Could you please guild me which one is better to use?

Comment: You probably need to go with a `Custom Intent` as your command does not seem to fall into any SiriKit's supported Domains. Just create a custom Intent and you can pick the Category as "Search" in the intent definition file.